# How do I edit the autosave interval of gedit?

Tags: gedit, gconf, source

Can you people tell me how to edit gedit, please?

I want to change the autosave feature so that it saves every 1 second, I was able to investigate further that I needed gconf-editor so I installed it but when I launched it and went to `/apps/gedit-2/preferences/editor/save/auto_save` it says:

This key has no schema, so I found this: http://www.mail-archive.com/scientific-linux-users@listserv.fnal.gov/msg08917.html

but it doesn't work.

I would really like to do this, but, otherwise, what is the best solution?

To change the source code and compile and gedit with autosaves of only 1 second?

Answer (score 2):

I have to ask, why do you need gedit to save every second?

Gedit's autosave interval seemingly can only be adjusted at a one-minute resolution. I can give you commands to do it on the command line, but you'll still be only able to set a 1-minute autosave timer.

```
gsettings set org.gnome.gedit.preferences.editor auto-save true
gsettings set org.gnome.gedit.preferences.editor auto-save-interval 1
```

Comment: I want to be able to save at 1 second because I am making 2 macros and I need to test them asap, so while I am making changes to 1, I bring the other to gedit and it saves automatically.

I used to do that in winxp I used notepad to autosave every 1 second and I'd do it and in here I want to do it also if possible